# Reading DOCX file content

Tags: java

```
 try {
     Pattern p =  Pattern.compile(b.toUpperCase());
     POITextExtractor text = ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(file);                        
     String text1 = text.getText();
     Matcher m = p.matcher(text1.toUpperCase());
} 
catch(IOException | OpenXML4JException | XmlException e){}
```

while running this code in NetBeans IDE 8.0 i am getting an error,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hwpf/OldWordFileFormatException
```

How to avoid this error.
package included is poi.ooxml

Comment: A quick Google search for classes, using grepcode, will often point you to the dependency that defines the class. The following search: [*"oldwordfileformatexception site:grepcode.com"*](https://www.google.com/?q=oldwordfileformatexception+site:grepcode.com) will be your best bet. The [first link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad/3.8/org/apache/poi/hwpf/OldWordFileFormatException.java) will tell you that the class exists in the following dependency `->` *org.apache.poi / poi-scratchpad*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `poi-scratchpad` jar to your classpath. It contains the missing class: `org.apache.poi.hwpf.OldWordFileFormatException.java`.

Answer (score 1):

you should add **poi-scratchpad.jar** to your build path or add this dependency 
to your **pom.xml** if maven project :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

you should use **poi-scratchpad** with **version 3.7** or newer one.